# Error sum of two matrix in function By using 2d array

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, function-call

```
    #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
int add(int x[3][3], int y[3][3],int z[3][3]);

int main()
{
 int x[3][3],y[3][3],z[3][3];
    cout<<"Enter value for x "<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
        
        cout<<"Enter the value of index "<<i<<","<<j<<" :";
        cin>>x[i][j];
        }
        
    }
    cout<<"Enter value for y "<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
        
        cout<<"Enter the value of index "<<i<<","<<j<<" :";
        cin>>y[i][j];
        }
        
    }
    
    cout<<"Your result is :";   
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
        
        cout<<add(x[3][3],y[3][3]);
        }
        cout<<endl;
        
    }
    return 0;}
int add(int x[3][3], int y[3][3],int z[3][3])
{
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        z[i][j]=x[i][j]+y[i][j];
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
       cout<<z[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
}
```

=================================================================================
you See the program in which I am want to add 2 matrix by using 2d array and I am also use Function `add(int x[3][3], int y[3][3],int z[3][3])` .  In this program One thing will give me error when i am try to compile it that  are `cout<<add(x[3][3],y[3][3])`  compiler say you have store three values in Function so write three values like `add(int x[3][3], int y[3][3],int z[3][3])` but WE know that at this piont we write only two integer that I am want to add that are declared in Function `z[i][j]=x[i][j]+y[i][j]`. So that program cannot be execute from me. So that why I am want your correction in this program .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `add` returns nothing though its return type is `int`.

So this statement

```
cout<<add(x[3][3],y[3][3]);
```

does not make a sense and moreover the function call has invalid arguments (the number of arguments and their types).

Maybe you mean

```
void add( const int x[3][3], const int y[3][3], int z[3][3]);
```

and

```
add( x, y, z );

cout<<"Your result is :";   
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        cout<< z[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    cout<<endl;
    
}
```

Here is your updated program.

```
#include <iostream>

const size_t N = 3;

void add( const int x[N][N], const int y[N][N], int z[N][N] );

int main() 
{
    int x[N][N], y[N][N], z[N][N];
    
    std::cout << "Enter value for x " << '\n';
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << "Enter the value of index " << i << "," << j << " : ";
            std::cin >> x[i][j];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Enter value for y " << '\n';
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << "Enter the value of index " << i << "," << j << " : ";
            std::cin >> y[i][j];
        }
    }

    add( x, y, z );
    
    std::cout << "Your result is:\n";
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << z[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void add( const int x[N][N], const int y[N][N], int z[N][N] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            z[i][j] = x[i][j] + y[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so you have declared three arguments so int to int conversion is not possible. First of All
define function like this

```
 int add(int x[3][3], int y[3][3])
{
    int z[3][3];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        z[i][j]=x[i][j]+y[i][j];
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
       cout<<z[i][j]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
}
```

secondly in main function to output result simple call function like

```
    cout<<"Your result is :"<<endl; 
    add(x,y);
```

Also Remove Z[3][3] from Declaration of Function.

Comment: "so int to int conversion is not possible"  Why is not the conversion int to int possible?:)

Comment: when you call a function pin main function  like cout<<add(int x[3][3], y[3][3],z[3][3]) ,compiler compares this to declaration, if we use void or other data type, conversion is possible.so we have to use function add(x,y,z) and if you want to convert ,data types must be different.

Comment: I have understood nothing. In my opinion the conversion from int to int is always possible.:)

Comment: May be you are correct, as you have more experience but what i have learnt, i have mention above.